# What do the 2 last numbers between '()' mean in 227 response to “ls” command?

Tags: linux, ftp

This question is related to FTP tool that can be found here:  ftp://ftp.linux.org.uk/pub/linux/Networking/netkit

If I run a command such like `ls` the output is the following:

```
227 Entering Passive Mode (192,0,2,1,104,31)
```

What do the 2 last numbers between `()` mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is the raw message from the FTP server, it's not generated by your client (netkit).

The last two numbers are the two bytes that comprise the remote port for the passive data connection.

In this case, the remote port is `(104 << 8) + 31`, or `(104 * 256) + 31` or 26655.

Comment: nice first answer!